# how to use Any(char.IsDigit) to extract the int value

Tags: c#

I have this line of code

```
    bool containsInt = "Sanjay 400".Any(char.IsDigit)
```

What I am trying to do is extract the 400 from the string but

```
Any(char.IsDigit)
```

only returns a true value. I am very new to coding and c# especially.

Comment: Do you want to extract 400 or do you want to extract the numbers of any string?

Comment: @DonMiguelSanchez number of any string

Comment: What is your spected value here? 400 or every digit like 4, 0, 0?

Comment: What do you want to happen with "Sanjay 400 in Mumbai 1234" ? Result should be "4001234"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int result = int.Parse(string.Concat("Sanjay 400".Where(char.IsDigit)));
```

Comment: `int.TryParse` would be a better choice

Answer (score 3):

As you already found out, you cannot use Any for extraction.

You would need to use the [Where](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where?view=net-7.0) method:

```
List<char> allInts = "Sanjay 400".Where(char.IsDigit).ToList();
```

The result will be a list containing all integers/digits from your string.

Ok if you are interested in the value as integer you would need to convert it again to a string and then into an integer. Fortunately string has a nice constructor for this.

```
char[] allIntCharsArray = "Sanjay 400".Where(char.IsDigit).ToArray();
int theValue = Convert.ToInt32(new string(allIntCharsArray));
```

If you are using .NET 5 or higher you could also use the new cool TryParse method without extra string conversion:

```
int.TryParse(allIntCharsArray, out int theValue);
```

Comment: your solution is clever, but if he want to have the value 400 this will not work

Comment: maybe add one more line: `numberString = string.Join("", allInts.ToArray());`

Comment: ^^ or as int : `int.TryParse(input.Where(char.IsDigit).ToArray(), out int myValue )`

Answer (score -1):

Use the [Regex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex?view=net-7.0)

```
var containsInt = Convert.ToInt32(Regex.Replace(@"Sanjay 400", @"\D", ""));
```

Regular expressions allow you to take only numbers and convert them into integers.

Comment: This is dangerous, what would happend if the number is larger than int?, it will produce an exception, you should use `int.TryParse`